# Merge GitHub branch into local branch

Tags: eclipse, github

I have the following situation: I have an application checked out from GitHub, made some changes and checked it in a local repository (Bitbucket). During months I added new functionality into this local repo.
In the meantime, the GitHub project has been further developed.
Now I'm looking for a way to merge the GitHub master branch into my local master branch. It would be nice if I can do it in eclipse. How should I proceed and how can I avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ***Git Repositories*** view:

1. Add an additional remote/upstream repository: right-click the node ***Remotes*** and choose ***Remote Remote...***
2. Fetch from the GitHub repository: see [*EGit User Guide - Fetching from other Repositories*](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories)
3. Merge changes from a remote branch of the GitHub repository into a local branch

Consider also to contribute back your changes to the GitHub project.

Comment: Great iw works! But I have one more question: After merging I've some conflicts and also with (as I think) very easy problems. For example an enum, which has the entries side by side in the local version and line by line in the GitHub version. Is it really necessary to manually solve such issues? That's strange.

Comment: Different formatting can prevent or make it more time-consuming to merge or to cherry-pick commits from the GitHub repository. You have to decide whether a different formatting is worth the extra effort on pulling the changes from GitHub.